# Is this question OK for Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, scope

I asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22653340/1420197) on *[Web Applications](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour)*. Then it was migrated.

Is this OK for Stack Overflow? Basically I don't provide any code in my question, so it can be closed quickly.

---

As I anticipated my question was closed (even on Web Applications), locked on Stack Overflow and migration was rejected.

Anyway, I solved my issue building a [Node.js](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Node.js) library that I published on [GitHub](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GitHub) and NPM: https://github.com/IonicaBizau/jsfiddle-api

Comment: What is NPM? The [official package manager for Node.js](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Npm_%28software%29)? Or a web site?

Comment: @PeterMortensen Exactly. It's the **N** ode **P** ackage **M** anager. My library was published [here](https://www.npmjs.org/package/jsfiddle-api).

Comment: That's interesting, first time I see "migration rejected".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think your question in it current form is off-topic because it says

> Is there any API that

And that is clearly asking to recommend a tool, which is [off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). I would recommend to reformulate your question to

> Is there a way to

In that case, you don't ask for a tool. If someone comes up with one, that is no problem.

If you really need to get a recommended tool, maybe [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) is the best place.

Comment: The issue is that I would use their API. I know how to get that object parsing the HTML of a get request, but I really want to know if0* there is an API*.  That's why I asked it on webapps.

Comment: @IonicăBizău: I understand your problem. Maybe you should ask a mod to return the question there if it isn't off-topic there. Else you have to comply to the policy.

Comment: I will flag it.

Comment: I think that is your best option. A mod can decide what suits best.

Comment: Just another thought. It is off-topic indeed for webapps. See the [off-topic list](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) (Creating or developing web applications).

Comment: Basically I ask for an existing feature of JSFiddle site. So, I don't think it's off-topic on webapps.

Comment: It think you should make that more clear. It seems to me you are asking for another API.

Comment: @IonicăBizău If you are asking for an existing feature of JSFiddle, why not just [go ask them](https://twitter.com/jsfiddle/)?

Comment: @Antony I opened an [issue](https://github.com/jsfiddle/jsfiddle-issues/issues/494) on the GitHub repository.

Comment: @PatrickHofman This is the correct answer. I [build a Node library that brings this feature](https://github.com/IonicaBizau/jsfiddle-api). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Some rules for asking a question on Stack Overflow are:

> How to Ask
>
> Is your question about programming?
>
> We prefer questions that can be answered, not just discussed.
>
> Provide details. Share your research.
>
> If your question is about this website, ask it on meta instead.

According to these rules, I think that it is a legitimate question. It is not about starting a discussion, you did your research, provided a code snippet (example of what you need), and asking for an API to get the code for a JSFiddle page so it can be answered. I've seen questions containing less information, and they were not removed, so I don't think that your question will be / should be closed.